# Qtinstaller framework

Tags: qt, installation, deployment

```
<pre><code>
function Component()
 {
 }

Component.prototype.isDefault = function()
  {
     return true;
  }

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
  {
     try
   {
     component.createOperations();
   }
   catch (e)
   {
    print(e);
   }
 if (installer.value("os") === "x11")
   {
    installer.performOperation("CreateDesktopEntry", "/usr/share/applications/YourApp.desktop",       "Version=1.0\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nExec=@TargetDir@/YourApp.sh\nName=YourApp_name\nIcon   =@TargetDir@YourApp_icon.png\nName[en_US]=YourApp_name");
    installer.performElevatedOperation("Copy", "/usr/share/applications/YourApp.desktop",   "@HomeDir@/Desktop/YourApp.desktop");
   }
  }
```

in the above script i want to write a service at /home/$user/.config/systemd/user/app.service
with content

```
 <pre><code>
 [Unit]
 Description=Example User Service

 [Service]
 ExecStart=/path/to/your/executable

 [Install]
 WantedBy=default.target
 </code></pre>
```

how i can write this service and start this service using above script?

i am able to make directory but unable to write the service at that directory location.